# Is there any way to wait a status using Callable in java?

Tags: java, threadpool, callable, futuretask

I have a problem: I create a Task that implements Callable. This task has a mission that wait for the status return to false. The status is depending on the server return. I dont know exactly when server return to false. So I create a task with name WaitForStatus as below. If the status is true this task will call Thread.sleep(); whenever status is false this task is done. How can I do?

Below is my code:

```
class WaitForStatusTask implements Callable<String> {

    private long waitTime;
    private boolean status;

    public WaitForStatusTask(boolean _status, int timeInMillis){
        this.waitTime=timeInMillis;
        this.status = _status;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        while(status){
            System.err.println("wait..");
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);

        }

    return "task done";         

   }

}
```

Can you correct this code for me?

Comment: Where is the code that changes the status to false and why do you take the status as a parameter in the c'tor? Can you query the status of the server from the while loop?

Comment: Yes, I can query the status of server as below.
 while (status) {
  //my code
}

Comment: The status is return from server. The task only wait for it return to false. Whenever It return to false then the task is done. Thats my idea

Answer (score -1):

The below piece of code is inefficient. A wait/notify (or concurrent utilities) will help you write clean code.

```
while(status){
            System.err.println("wait..");
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);

        }
}
```

Call get() on the Future to wait for the response of the task completion.